# Why does "ImageIO.read(URL input)" fail on some images on Weblogic 12c?

Tags: java, image, weblogic, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

Alright, I have a problem that is driving me crazy!

I have a web application deployed on Weblogic 12.1.1 -i.e.:Weblogic 12c

At some point, I want to read an image File using:

```
BufferedImage templateImage = ImageIO.read(new URL(url));
```

The previous line fails on **some** images with the following so-stupid message:

```
For input string: ""
```

Some advised that I change the HTTP handler for Weblogic using the the following parameter:

```
-DUseSunHttpHandler=true
```

and it solved the problem yet I can't implement this solution as it will be very risky.

What made me more crazy is that when I modify the picture using "Paint", adding/removing some dummy colors and/or shapes, it passed!!

(Although not all changes will make it pass).

This is my first question here and I'd really appreciate your help.

P.S.: Problem appears only on "Weblogic 12c", not 11g or anything else.

**Edit**: below is the Stack Trace:

---

```
java.io.IOException: For input string: ""
        at weblogic.utils.http.HttpChunkInputStream.initChunk(HttpChunkInputStre
am.java:69)
        at weblogic.utils.http.HttpChunkInputStream.skip(HttpChunkInputStream.ja
va:215)
        at weblogic.utils.http.HttpChunkInputStream.skipAllChunk(HttpChunkInputS
tream.java:395)
        at weblogic.utils.http.HttpChunkInputStream.close(HttpChunkInputStream.j
ava:291)
        at weblogic.net.http.KeepAliveStream.close(KeepAliveStream.java:122)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1405)
```

---

Comment: Is there a stack trace to go with that error message? Also, note that using `ImageIO.read(URL)` will use `URL.openStream()` to create an `InputStream` to read from. You could try to read the contents from the URL yourself, into a byte array, and use `ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))` to narrow down the issue to either network or image reading.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've added the Stack Trace above.
One thing that worth to be mentioned is that when I tried to construct a File object for the image file and pass it to the "read" method, it worked!

Comment: Yeah it's most probably a Weblogic bug, will try one of the alternatives instead, Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm almost sure now it's a WebLogic Bug, I rewrote the code to be like:

```
URL url = new URL("url")
File file = new File("New File Path");
InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        try {
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
        } finally {
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
}
BufferedImage actualImage = ImageIO.read(file);
```

The key difference in the new code is that it passes the read() method a [File] instance instead of a [URL] instance.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace reveals that `ImageIO.read(...)` is actually done reading the image (could be a good image, could be it didn't work), and is closing the stream...

The stack trace also reveals that the problem is caused by the WebLogic class `HttpChunkInputStream`. Because of this, it seems to be a bug in WebLogic, in handling [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) (note that it *could* also be that the server you are connecting to has a bug in its chunked transfer encoding).

When you modify the image in Paint, a side effect is that it probably makes the image a a few bytes smaller or a few bytes larger, and thus you don't hit the bug.

From this, it seems like using the `-DUseSunHttpHandler=true` switch or upgrading WebLogic is your best bet. Alternatively, you could try to read the the contents from the `URL` yourself, into a byte array, and use `ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))` to narrow down the issue to either network or image reading. You can also ignore the `IOException` from `close()` (but there might be that the data really is corrupted, so this isn't 100% fool proof).